# Alternately reorder nodeList based on class

Tags: jquery

I have a nodeList that is set up something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to reorder the div inside #container such that the output is alternating class names:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
  <div class="class-a"></div>
  <div class="class-b"></div>
</div>
```

What would be the best approach to handle this issue? Although in this example there are equal class-a and class-b items, there could be any number or none of either. As long as there is either of the two it will alternate.

Comment: And there's only two different classes, not three, four etc

Comment: Yes there may share other classes, but those two classes are there just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it although there may be an easier way.

```
  var divs = $("#container > div"); // get the divs in #container
  var length = divs.length; // get the length once and reuse it

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var currentClass = (i % 2 === 0) ? "class-a" : "class-b"; // class-a for evens. class-b for odds

    if (!$(divs[i]).hasClass(currentClass)) { // if not currentClass
      for (var j = i + 1; j < length; j++) { // loop through remaining divs
        if ($(divs[j]).hasClass(currentClass)) { // find next div with currentClass
          // move next element with currentClass from index j to index i
          var element = divs[j];
          divs.splice(j, 1);
          divs.splice(i, 0, element);
          break; // break inner loop
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $("#container").empty().append(divs);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9bkrs5s1/)

Comment: That worked!! I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: @QuintonJasonJr No problem but would you please accept the answer if you're happy with it?